# What is difference between def interface and dto inerface in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am working on the project, which was started by someone else. There are **two interface files** in the model folder **def and dto**. The difference between **def and dto interface files** is not clear to me. Could any expereince developer let me know what is the difference and when and how to use **dto** instead of **def** and viceversa. Thanks in advance.

**vendor-def.interface.ts:**

```js
import { SourceType, VendorType } from '../shared/enums/vendor-type.enum';

export interface VendorDef {
  vendorId: string;
  companyCode: string;
  name: string;
  acronym: string;
  alias: string;
  legalId: string;
  vendorType: VendorType;
  sourceType: SourceType;
  fiscalCode: string;
}


export interface VendorFormDef {
  sourceType: SourceType;
  companyCode?: string;
  previousMainCompany?: string;
}

export interface InUsageDef {
  acronym: boolean;
  legalId: boolean;
  fiscalCode: boolean;
}
```

**vendor-dto.interface.ts**

```js
import { SourceType, VendorType } from '../shared/enums/vendor-type.enum';

export interface VendorDto {
  data: VendorDataDto[] | VendorDataDto;
  errors?: VendorErrorsDto;
}

export interface VendorDataDto {
  attributes: VendorAttributesDto;
  id: string;
}

export interface VendorErrorsDto {
  code: string;
  title: string;
  detail: string;
}

export interface VendorCreateDto {
  companyCode: string;
  name: string;
  acronym: string;
  legalId: string;
  fiscalCode: string;
  vendorType: VendorType;
  sourceType: SourceType;
}
```

Comment: You should consult the original author

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, it's used to separate what your API gives you from the objects you will manipulate.

- `VendorDTO` is your API response (hence the presence of the `data` and `errors` fields)
- `VendorDef` is the definition of the object you will manipulate in your app.

It is common to have a transformer from `VendorDTO` to `VendorDef` for when you request the data and a transformer from `VendorDef` to `VendorDTO` for when you want to push an addition/update on your API.

*It is not restricted to Typescript or Angular, so you might want to check your question's tags.*